# Pydrake - Adding Revolute Joint to Plant

Tags: python, drake

I'm trying to add a revolute joint to my plant. Here is my code:

```
m_s_joint = RevoluteJoint(name="m_to_s_joint", frame_on_parent=frame_on_m,
                                       frame_on_child=frame_on_upper_c,
                                       axis=np.array([1., 0., 0.]),
                                       damping=0.0)
ma_su_joint = plant.AddJoint(m_s_joint)
```

When I print the joint:

```
print("joint: ", ma_su_joint)
```

I get:

```
joint:  <RevoluteJoint_[float] name='ma_to_su_joint' index=1 model_instance=1>
```

so it's clear the joint is being formed. But then I get this error:

```
    plant.Finalize()
RuntimeError: This multibody element does not belong to the supplied MultibodyTree.
```

Any ideas on why?

Comment: Figured it out and commenting for others: When you generate a fixed offset frame you need to AddFrame to register it. I was calling this frame without having added it

Comment: Thanks for updating! You may want to do the "answer your own question" thing on StackOverflow, just so people are aware that this question is answered ('cause I'm sure others will come across this as well!)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out: The Revolute Joint calls a frame that I created but I never called AddFrame to register it to the plant. Doing that fixed the problem.